# Can Perl output runtime errors for unitialized variable references, instead of silently exiting the script?

Tags: perl, warnings

I use Perl v5.22.1 on Windows 10 x64. 
My scripts contain

```
use strict;
use warnings "all";
```

I sometimes find that due to my error, an undefined variable is referenced.  My experience is that Perl silently exits the script without displaying any error or warning.

Are there any additional settings or options that would enable warnings about referencing uninitialized variables?

I found some [guidance on setting exit codes here](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/die.html#exit-EXPR), but I would prefer an actual error or warning naming the variable if that is possible.

Comment: [Edit] the question and provide a [example] of the behavior you claim to get.

Comment: Perl *always* displays a message if it causes an application to exit.

Comment: Perl never "displays" a message. It gives a message to something and maybe that something displays it. So, the trick in these cases sometimes is to figure out what's seeing the output and what that thing is doing with it. Show us how you are running programs and so on.

Answer (score 1):

There are three ways the Perl interpreter will cause a program to exit:

- By throwing an exception. If this exception is uncaught, the stringification of the exception will be printed to STDERR, and the program will exit.
- By encountering a severe condition. A message (possibly including the word "panic") will be printed to STDERR, and the program will exit.
- In response to a call to `exit` or by reaching the end of the program. No message will be output by the Perl interpreter since it didn't initiate the exit (and thus has no way of knowing why the programmed exited).

A program will also exit if killed by the OS (e.g. in response to some uncaught signals).

So, in all cases where the Perl interpreter initiates the exit, it already outputs a message.

So, you are requesting that Perl does what Perl already does.

So, your request is moot.

Comment: Since you don't say "display" anymore, my comments are now irrelevant :)